# How to send 1 file at a time? Wait then Send Next - Mobx / Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios, mobx

I have multiple pictures that a user uploads, once they hit the upload button I want to start going and uploading each picture, I first like to start with one at a time and maybe try for a batch of 5 at a time.

```
  @action
   uploadAllFiles = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
         runInAction(async () => {
            const file = this.files[i];
            file.uploading = true;
             var data = new FormData();
            data.append('folderName', '4141515');
            data.append('file', file.fileObject);
            await axiosGenericInstance.post('/Images', data);
            this.files.remove(file);
         });
    }
  };
```

but I get

> Since strict-mode is enabled, changing observed observable values
>   outside actions is not allowed. Please wrap the code in an `action` if
>   this change is intended. Tried to modify:

So I am not doing this right.

Comment: What does `runInAction` function do ?

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this :

```
export function getDetails(n, dataArray) {
return async(dispatch) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
      myService.getDetails(dataArray['x'][i]['y'])
        .then(res => {
          let item = dataArray['x'][i]['y']
          dispatch({type: types.DETAILS_GRAPH, item, i, res});
          })
        .catch(error => {
          dispatch({type: types.SET_ERROR, error});      
        });
  }
 //sleep(1) here if time needed between 2 calls
 };
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should `await` runInAction

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    // first write await      
    await  runInAction(async () => {
        const file = this.files[i];
        file.uploading = true;
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('folderName', '4141515');
        data.append('file', file.fileObject);
        await axiosGenericInstance.post('/Images', data);
        this.files.remove(file);
    });
}
```